# How to view Google Chrome Media Cache in macOS?

Tags: software-recommendation, google-chrome

I am able to access the Google caches on macOS here:

`~/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome/Profile 2/Media Cache`

But the files are as here:

[image]

I want to see them in their original form. While I can do this using tool on Windows, I couldn't find any for macOS. How can I do this on macOS?

**Extra info**: I'm developing [a game](https://katan.io/) with pixi.js and all the assets look good on most other browsers. But Chrome's cache somehow messes things up. I want to understand how the cache is held & find a way to fix the problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Apple hardware, software or services in the [scope defined](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @NimeshNeema the problem is there are tools for windows to extract the images but I couldn't find any for mac, does it count?

Comment: Please [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/357381/edit) and mention that clearly in the question. With it in place, the question is on-topic.

Comment: The second answer here looked promising https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133490/how-can-i-read-chrome-cache-files. But it didn't work on my Mac. It might point you in the right direction tho. Just a thought.